# Building an adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

Helo Everyone, here is my problem.

using

```
> visite_cliente <- aggregate(info.uso.2$N,list(CodCliente = info.uso.2$CodCliente, museo = info.uso.2$museo),sum)
```

I created the following matrix :

```
> head(visite_cliente)

   CodCliente           museo      x
1       1247 ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA 1
2       3260 ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA 1
3       4104 ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA 1
4       4145 ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA 1
5       5368 ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA 1
6       5530 ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA 1
```

CodCliente is my customer's ID, while "museo" is the museum visited by the customer (I have 139 museums in the dataframe), and X value represent the times that customer visited the museum in a year.
In "visite_cliente" you can find the same ID more than one time if the customer visited more than a museum.

I should create an adjacency matrix in which I have as columns the museums (so 139 columns), the IDs in the rows, and insert the times the customer visited each museum in the matrix.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome ianux22! Could you provide a reproducible example to create the `visite_cliente` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic long-wide reshape problem

just do

```
library(data.table)

dcast(data = visite_cliente, CodCliente ~ museo, value.var = "x")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but it works. Since your data had no reuse of CodCliente, only one museo and no revisits to a museum,  I added a few more rows.   If you make the row names be the CodCliente  and the column names be the museo,  you can simply use those as the indices into the adjacency matrix.

```
## sample data
visite_cliente = read.table(text="CodCliente   museo      x
1       1247 'ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA' 1
2       3260 'ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA' 1
3       4104 'ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA' 1
4       4145 'ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA' 1
5       5368 'ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA' 1
6       5530 'ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA' 1
7       5530 'ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA' 1
8       1234 'MUSEO EGIZIO'  1
9       1247 'MUSEO EGIZIO'  1",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


Adj = matrix(0, nrow=length(unique(visite_cliente$CodCliente)),
        ncol=length(unique(visite_cliente$museo)),
        dimnames = list(rownames=unique(visite_cliente$CodCliente),
            colnames=unique(visite_cliente$museo)))

for(row in 1:nrow(visite_cliente)) {
    Adj[as.character(visite_cliente[row,1]), visite_cliente[row,2]] =
        Adj[as.character(visite_cliente[row,1]), visite_cliente[row,2]] + 
            visite_cliente[row,3]
}
Adj
        colnames
rownames ABBAZIA DI FRUTTUARIA MUSEO EGIZIO
    1247                     1            1
    3260                     1            0
    4104                     1            0
    4145                     1            0
    5368                     1            0
    5530                     2            0
    1234                     0            1
```

Comment: Thank you! I already used the function "Dcast" as Felipe suggested me because it's easier, but i'll save what you wrote because it will be very helpful in the fucture!